# File Explorer Move shows comparison window, despite files having same Name, Date, Size. Does it mean the files have internal difference, or corrupted?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer

[Screenshot: File Move Operation.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voa4H.png) attached.

I initiated Move operation within File Explorer, between two distinct folders. I have multiple identical files in them, hence this dialog box was expected. Windows policy is, if the files have same Name, Date and Size, then it will simply show the bottom checkbox like:

☑ skip the files with same date and size.

However in this unique instance, files that satisfy these conditions are still being shown here for comparison. Does it mean that the files have some differences other than the above 3 conditions? Or maybe the files are corrupted?

Someone with Windows expertise can please throw some light on the issue. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Hunting through the file Properties, comparing same files present between the two distinct folders, size(bytes), modified time, etc. everything from both files is same. I only noticed the below difference, when clicking Security > Advanced tab:

[Screenshot different properties.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieSdV.png)

File that was only on Windows (never handled by Linux) has the `Resource Properties` drop-down button, which has the following information `IMAGELOAD: 1`, this is not present in the file that was handled by Linux. Would wish someone to throw light on this, on what does it mean and does it affect file comparison.

Windows 10 21H1 (OS build 19043.1110), up-to-date.

Comment: NTFS attributes can differ and this will make the files appear different.  These attributes can be ACLs (access control lists) to include differing permissions per-user between source and destination.  By now, the dialog with the 'skip the files...' should offer more choices..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have recently done copy / move ops over these folders (external disk) using Ubuntu Linux, but never opened or modified while there. Does that have any relation to this? I know Linux can mess with NTFS file permissions, but these files are on an open, unencrypted, external disk and not ties to any user or have any access rules. Does Linux still modify these attributes while performing simple copying / moving within NTFS drive itself?

Comment: Have you moved files created on Windows with Linux?

Comment: @harrymc Yes all these files were downloaded on Windows, only opened, never modified. The said folder contains entirely .pdfs of various reference manuals. I only moved them around inside Linux. All operations were within the external NTFS drive itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog shows that the compared pairs have identical attributes
as regarding date and data size
(or one attribute would have been shown in bold).

This only means that the difference is in other attributes than
the ones that are shown.

I can see two possibilities, both arising from having moved Windows
files via Linux and losing these attributes:

1. Permissions : Moving files preserves their attributes,
   such as owner, but Linux does not preserve Windows permissions.
2. Data streams: Windows stores metadata in some files as
   [alternate streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams),
   which are not visible in Explorer, only visible via programs that
   access them specifically (for example Explorer).

If you wish to know more about alternate data streams:

- [What Is File Streams And How to Make Good Use of Them?](https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-files-streams-and-how-to-make-good-use-of-them/)
- Microsoft's [Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams).

Comment: I didn't mention the alternate streams Mr. @harrymc.  I never think about it because windows never gave us a way to SEE them :) .. nice addition

Comment: @harrymc please can you review the question EDIT, although I am not sure if this is the cause.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas please can you review the question EDIT, although I am not sure if this is the cause.

Comment: EDIT analysis: I can't find any info about it. If I had to guess, I would say that this is an alternate data stream containing an image (IMAGELOAD). It might be the image to display in Explorer (or some other application) for representing the PDF to the user. I can't guess which Windows application has embedded it in the PDF. Linux wouldn't copy this stream, only the main data stream, which is why the files are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *any* doubt about a file's integrity, use the Windows CMD file-compare tool, [fc](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-compare-two-files-command-prompt-windows-10), e.g.,

```
  fc <path\file1.ext> <path\file1.ext>
```

or, if you prefer a GUI, use a third-party tool such as free [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/).

If you don't have the original for that file, try a few tests with another, keeping the original file and copying it (or zipping it, which uses checksums to verify the file integrity, and move the copy as well as the original), then diffing the original and move version.

As @SeñorCMasMas states in a comment, likely the difference is an attribute that is *not* displayed in that dialog, such those listed below:

```
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  O   Offline attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
  X   No scrub file attribute.
  V   Integrity attribute.
  P   Pinned attribute.
  U   Unpinned attribute.
  B   SMR Blob attribute.
```

**N.B.** Linux may not handle NTFS attributes exactly the way MS Windows does. For example, Windows has added information on frame width, [play] length, authors, etc., which are not necessarily journaled by Linux. Of course, by itself, Windows cannot even read the Linux ext*n* file systems. See Doctorow's novella on incompatible (and unrepairable) products, [Unauthorized Bread](https://craphound.com/unauthorizedbread/).

Comment: So Windows actually uses all these additional attributes while comparing two files?

Comment: That, I don't know, but if you want to be sure if your copy process makes no change except *perhaps* to attributes, which are external to the file data, you could test it easily.

Comment: Update: I did the `FC` command, even trying various parameters of comparison: `/a` ASCII comparison, `/b` Binary comparison, `/L` , `/u` UNICODE comparison, etc. however all results were **no difference encountered**. I am not sure that `FC` does the comparison of permissions or any attributes that Windows might have (hypothetically) assigned. Trying the move operation from one folder to other again gave the same dialog as before. Basically there are no differences evident on the exterior.

Comment: @ShubhamDeshmukh, the *attributes* are not stored in the file, but in the NTSF system: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789708/where-does-ntfs-stores-file-attributes . Most diff tools, including fc, are concerned *only* with the contents of the file itself, not attributes.